# Deformation gradient conservation law from Lagrangian to Eulerian formulation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, classical-mechanics, hyperbolic-pde, fluid-dynamics

In the following, I use the standard notation for (solid) mechanics and conservation laws, i.e. $F$ the formation gradient, $H$ the cofactor, $v$ the velocity field and $J$ the Jacobian. Moreover, $X$ is for the initial configuration where functions and fields are expressed using a bar and $x$ is for the mapped {current) configuration.

The rate of deformation gradient can be expressed as:
$$ 
\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = (\nabla \bar{v}) F.
$$
Now I know how to derive the total (TLF) 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_V F \; dV = \int_{\partial V} \bar{v}\otimes N \; dA$$ and updated (ULF) 
$$\int_{v(t)} J^{-1} \left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\right\vert_{X} \; dv = \int_{v(t)} \nabla\cdot (v\otimes H) dv$$ 
lagrangian formulations.

I would like to get, if it exists, the Eulerian formulation of the above, as well as the ALE and Total ALE formulation of it.

To do so, I tried to start from TLF, I switch to the current configuration $v(t)$ using $J$ and I use the Reynold's transport theorem to get rid of the total time derivative on the integral and to get the convective term. I end up with:

$$
\int_{v(t)} \frac{\partial J^{-1}F}{\partial t} + \nabla\cdot(J^{-1}F\otimes v) \; dv = \int_{v(t)} \nabla\cdot (v\otimes H^{-1}) \; dv
$$

Are the mathematics correct? And can I reach these formulations? May I say that I prefer integral forms..

Comment: The notation is not clear. $v$ is the velocity or volume ? Also, the first equation should read $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=\nabla \tilde v. F$

Comment: $v$ is the velocity while $V$ and $v(t)$ are initial and current volumes. I could not use omega.